# How to add the shutdown options to the unity

Tags: unity, shutdown, reboot, logout

How to add the options:

- shutdown
- reboot
- logout
- Suspend
- Hibernate
- Lock Screen

to the unity dash as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [atareao](http://www.atareao.es/author/yyyxfsgj/) team.

With reference to [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/03/add-shutdown-restart-power-commands-unity-dash?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20d0od%20%28OMG!%20Ubuntu!%29) I found a pretty solution to share.

Install Power Commands for unity dash in Ubuntu 12.04 – 14.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install power-commands
```

After installation has completed the items will be available to find in the Dash almost instantly. If you don’t see them you may need to log out and back in to force the Dash to detect them.

To uninstall at a later date you simply need to open the Ubuntu Software Centre, search for ‘Power Commands’ and hit the ‘remove’ button.